# Are there situations where an ExplictWait is not working?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I know about the three different types of waiting you can use in Selenium. I know why Thread.Sleep and ImplicitWait are never a good choice. So I'm always using ExplicitWaits, for instance to wait till a button is clickable. However, from time to time one or two tests in a collection of hundred tests fails because the Explictwait seems to fail.

I read the very interesting article: https://bocoup.com/weblog/a-day-at-the-races
about the reason why tests can fail from time to time and Explicit wait as the solution for this intermittent failures. This made me even more convinced about using ExplictWaits.

So I wonder is there anybody who knows situations were an Explicitwait is not doing the right job.

This is my C# code for waiting till a Webelement is clickable:

```
    public static Boolean waitElementToBeClickable(IWebDriver driver, int seconds, IWebElement webelement)
    {
        Boolean clickable = true;
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webelement));
        }
        catch
        {
            clickable = false;
        }
        return clickable;
    }
```

Comment: `Explicitwait` is doing right job while you might use it wrong. Show real example of issue, so we can help you to deal with it

Comment: There was for example an issue with Bootstrap Modal Fade where my click on a button despite my ExplicitWait didn't reached the button but ended in the Bootstrap Dialog. I solved this issue with the help off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546217/suggestions-for-getting-selenium-to-play-nice-with-bootstrap-modal-fade

Comment: Was it `chromedriver`? It seem to be `chromedriver` issue, but not `ExplicitWait`. You just need to use another condition for `ExplicitWait`

Comment: This question is opinion based. You should read about `FluentWait`, and know that `ExplicitWait` is just a special case of fluent.

Comment: It's chromedriver I use. What other condition do you suggest?

Comment: @Frank, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632230/getting-element-is-not-clickable-exception-while-click-on-a-menu-link/41632565#41632565. It's `Java`, but the point is same for all programming languages. I hope I understood you correctly and this is exactly the same issue, you've faced

Comment: @Andersson, Yes this is the same issue as I described in my comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632230/getting-element-is-not-clickable-exception-while-click-on-a-menu-link/41632565#41632565 is the same questions as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546217/suggestions-for-getting-selenium-to-play-nice-with-bootstrap-modal-fade I upvoted your answer  in 41632230. When I will find another situation where ExplicitWait is not enough to finish a test succesful I come back with a new question.